# Using reserved keyword in JPA / Hibernate entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Lets assume that I have to use reserved keyword even if it's incorrect. I'm being forced to rename table to new name, which is reserved keyword.

Now I saw every recommended way, how to escape the name, to fail:

A) Using hibernate config property:

```
hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
```

having entity annotated just like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LIMIT", schema = "something")
```

does work, but sadly also escapes schema, meaning it actually does not work, as statements like:

```
select * from "something"."LIMIT"
```

won't work.

B) Annotating entity as

```
@Entity(name = "LIMIT")
@Table(name = "\"LIMIT\"", schema = "something")
```

or

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "[LIMIT]", schema = "something")
```

is unable to see existing table. With it I'll get exception as:

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [something.`limit`]

If I turn of hibernate start-up validation, I'll get exceptions with existing queries, like:

```
QuerySyntaxException: LimitEntity is not mapped
```

C) annotating entity just:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LIMIT", schema = "something")
```

will work just OK, but hibernate fails to auto-generate schema out of it in tests

What is the correct escaping of reserved keywords in JPA/hibernate? We need everything to work, not just something, meaning running app, autogenerating table for tests, ...

version:

```
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>5.2.17.Final</version>
```

Comment: Well, can't you just migrate your LIMIT Table to something more meaningful then?

Comment: First sentence of this question creates assumption, that I cannot. Thus I cannot. It's incorrect, I know that, but world sometimes is as such, and this should be supported anyways.